# Javascript - ensure a string field contains certain char and numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a React app and have an input field that needs to be in the following exact format:

char 1,2,3 and 4 must be VTF_  and then the rest of the string must contain numbers.

so VTF_12345678 is valid, VRT_3450985 is invalid, VTF_48957jkljlk is invalid.

Here is what i have tried.

```
if(!test || !test.startsWith("VTF_") || test.indexOf((/^[0-9]+$/), 5) == -1){

//display error
```

Comment: VFT_\d+$ Use the regex

Answer (score 5):

You don't want `indexOf`, just a regular expression and the `test` method will do it

```
if (!/^VTF_\d+$/.test(test)) {
    // Not valid
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(test) {
    if (!/^VTF_\d+$/.test(test)) {
        console.log(test, " <= Not valid");
    } else {
        console.log(test, " <= Valid");
    }
}

check("VTF_12345678");
check("VRT_3450985");
check("VTF_48957jkljlk");
```

- `^` means "start of input"
- `VTF_` means those characters, literally
- `\d+` means "one or more digits"
- `$` means "end of input"

`test` returns `true` if the string matches the regular expression, `false` if not.

Comment: Thank you... didn't know the `test` method existed. Works great.